# How do I check that each value is being pushed to the second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of 6 values, of which want 4 unique random values.

Currently, I retrieve 4 random values from the list, but not unique.

When I try and check the value already exists it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Is my logic what is wrong? If so could someone point me in the right direction?

```js
const Teams = ["Tetra", "Tiny Tetra", "Tetra terriers", "OneSeasonWonders", "Yurtie Ahern", "Liverpool"];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let pickedTeam = [];
  let randomTeam = Math.floor(Math.random() * Teams.length);
  pickedFromArray = Teams[randomTeam];
  //console.log(pickedFromArray);
  if (pickedTeam.includes(pickedFromArray, 0)) {
    randomTeam = Math.floor(Math.random() * Teams.length);
  } else {
    pickedTeam.push(pickedFromArray);
  }
  console.log("Slot " + i + " - " + pickedTeam);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@heartleth's answer is correct, but I wanted to point out that you won't always get 4 elements from the loop unless you remove the random team from the `Teams` array to prevent it being selected again.

```js
let pickedTeam = [];
const Teams = ["Tetra", "Tiny Tetra", "Tetra terriers", "OneSeasonWonders", "Yurtie Ahern", "Liverpool"];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let randomTeam = Math.floor(Math.random() * Teams.length);
  let pickedFromArray = Teams[randomTeam];

  if (!pickedTeam.includes(pickedFromArray)) {
    pickedTeam.push(pickedFromArray);
    Teams.splice(randomTeam, 1);
  }

  console.log("Slot " + i + " - " + pickedTeam);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `pickedTeam` out.

```js
const Teams = ["Tetra","Tiny Tetra","Tetra terriers","OneSeasonWonders","Yurtie Ahern","Liverpool"];
let pickedTeam = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let randomTeam = Math.floor(Math.random()* Teams.length);
    pickedFromArray = Teams[randomTeam];
    //console.log(pickedFromArray);
    if (pickedTeam.includes(pickedFromArray,0)) {
        randomTeam = Math.floor(Math.random()* Teams.length);
    }
    else{
        pickedTeam.push(pickedFromArray);
    }
   
    console.log("Slot " + i + " - " + pickedTeam);
}
```

Comment: An oversight on my part, thank you. I have accepted @a.mola answer for the reason i get 4 teams every time. Appreciate the attention, thank you.